# PHP file upload gets failure when using wireless broadband?

Tags: php, file-upload, wireless

When Using the wireless broadband the file more than 97 kb gets failure and php error code return 3.That is for file upload partially.It only happens for the wireless network(using USB modem).If I am using the wired connection it works fine.

1. What are the reasons for error code 3 in php?
2. why my file failure in wireless network only?

below I pasted my php code.Front end we are using flex.

```
   ini_set("max_execution_time",172000);
   $filep=$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
   $name=$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
   $name=str_replace(" ","_",$name);
   $path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."unittesting/".$name;

   $test=move_uploaded_file($filep,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."unittesting/".$name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a network layer issue and nothing at all to do with PHP. Perhaps you'd have better luck asking on superuser.com ?

Comment: do you have any idea on this?If so please post it.And also I don't know how to migrate this question.

Comment: Call your wireless broadband provider.